# How to get the application exit code from the Windows command shell?

Tags: batch-file

Of course, if possible, without any VBScript-like scripts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lastnico,

Hello, I think I have a solution to your problem. Try the following:

Try this at your command prompt:

```
C:\> cmd /c exit /b 4

C:\> echo %errorlevel%
```

The result should be 4.

Here is a screen shot of my result:

[Result of Code http://img691.imageshack.us/img691/7473/cmdc.jpg](http://img691.imageshack.us/img691/7473/cmdc.jpg)

I hope this helps,

### Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The exit code is stored in the **ERRORLEVEL** environment variable:

```
echo %ERRORLEVEL%
```

To test it you can create a simple batch file that exits using the exit code passed as parameter:

exit_code.bat

```
@exit /b %1
```

Testing:

```
> exit_code.bat 8
> echo %ERRORLEVEL%
8
```

Comment: my command line is always returning 9009 error code. Do you know why?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: It's just a typo in his code, it's supposed to be %1 instead of %i, no reason to downvote.

Comment: I can't un-downvote until the answer is edited.  Kaniabi, if you edit your answer to correct, I should be able to un-downvote.  Thanks!

Comment: Ops. Typo fixed.
Thanks all for the feedback.

Comment: Lastnico: Strange return code. I tried to execute with the typo and it always returns 0, not 9009.